# Apache2 redirecting

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http-status-code-301

I am new to apache2 configuration and as far as I could determine the server setup is correct and it works fine on mydomain.com

The problem is even if I explicitly type the url www.mydomain.com, I get 301 redirect from apache to mydomain.com. I tried rewrite rules only to end up in infinite loop.

We actually want to do reverse - mydomain.com should redirect to www.mydomain.com but as indicated above, I get infinite redirect loop until browser gives up.

I have searched the configuration and could not find any mention of mydomain.com so thinking that there is some external configuration (DNS lookup?) coming into picture which is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check with the DNS server to verify you have a CNAME for www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

If this is for local PC (testing and development) you need to edit your host file in windows or hosts in linux.

I locally resolved the problem that I had by creating a virtual DNS server for my local network (ubuntu server).

```
    install bind
apt-get install bind9 -y

cd /etc/bind

vim named.conf.options

And uncomment forwarders and two rows bellow and instead of 0.0.0.0 enter google's dns IP (8.8.8.8).

service bind9 restart

vim named.conf.options

zone "YOURDOMAIN NAME" {
        type master;
        file "db.site.com";
        notify yes;
        };

cp db.local /var/cache/bind/db.site.com
cd /var/cache/bind/
vim db.sajt1.rs

$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     admin. admin.itlink.edu. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN NS ns.YOURDOMAINNAMEHERE.
        IN      A       192.168.1.10 replace this with the IP of your PC that has apache installed
ns      A       192.168.1.10 replace this with the IP of your PC that has apache installed
www     A       192.168.1.10 replace this with the IP of your PC that has 



service bind9 restart
```

If you put the IP of the ubuntu server as your dns everything will function properly (since all sites that cant be resolved will be sent to google DNS and it will do it for you).
But this is for local network only.

Comment: If you were not referring to local network resolving then my apologies.